# VS Code kotlin spring debug

Tags: spring, kotlin, visual-studio-code, debugging

It was necessary to remove the user development environment from vs code. Python, Java, and Rust work automatically, but not with spring boot applications for kotlin - this is a problem. They run, but I don't understand how to debug them. The kotlin developer from fwd does not work with spring boot when I run grand le boot Run --debug-jvm and run.json, but in that case I do not know how to set a breakpoint.

launch.json

```
{
    "type": "kotlin",
    "name": "Debug",
    "request": "attach",
    "hostName": "localhost",
    "port": 5005
}
```

I expect that vs code can be configured so that kotlin spring boot applications can be run and debugged.